# How to return true each time something is added to an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, return

I created a function that will add an item to an empty array up to a const max value.  However, I can't figure out how to return true each time an item is successfully added to the array (and false each time an item couldn't be added).
Here is what I've got:

```
let adoptedDogs = [];
const maxDogs = 2;

function getDog( name ){
console.log( 'dog's name:', name );

if( adoptedDogs.length < maxDogs ){
  adoptedDogs.push( name );
}
}

getDog( 'Spot' );
getDog( 'Daisy' );
getDog( 'Chester' );
```

Comment: Add a `return true` and a `return false` in the relevant places. You're close.

Comment: By the way, your code allows you to have 1 more dog than `maxDogs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let adoptedDogs = [];
const maxDogs = 2;

function getDog(name){

if( adoptedDogs.length < maxDogs ){
  adoptedDogs.push( name );
  return true;
}
return false;
}

console.log(getDog('Spot'));
console.log(getDog('Daisy'));
console.log(getDog('Chester'));
```

Comment: If you find it useful.Please accept this as answer.

Comment: Thank you, John!  It was the `console.log(getDog('Spot'));` I was missing.  You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the length is smaller than the wanted count and push and return `true` otherwise return `false`.

```js
let adoptedDogs = [];
const maxDogs = 2;

function getDog(name) {
    console.log('dog\'s name:', name);
    if (adoptedDogs.length < maxDogs) {
        adoptedDogs.push(name);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

console.log(getDog('Spot'));
console.log(getDog('Daisy'));
console.log(getDog('Chester'));
console.log(adoptedDogs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `getDog` return a boolean value:

```
function getDog( name ){
  console.log( "dog's name:" + name );

  if(adoptedDogs.length < maxDogs ){
     adoptedDogs.push( name );
     return true;
  } return false;
}

console.log(getDog("dog name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, it would be useful to name your functions such that they describe what they actually doing. getDog() is not getting a dog, it is adding a dog to an array, so perhaps addDog() would be more appropriate? This will make your own code easier to read, more complex stackoverflow questions easier to understand, and, to some extent, make you code self documenting.

I appreciate this is a trivial example, and you're probably going to change it anyway, and.., but just thought I'd mention it.

All the best.

(sorry this is an answer, I don't have enough rep to comment)

Comment: I can see what you're saying, for sure.  However, for my class we're using physical examples for our coding, which may not have been clear from my limited context.  So although, addThing may be better for adding to an array and keeping things clear, I need to illustrate the physical action I'm doing (getting a dog), and that if I want to get some dogs, I have to take into consideration that I'm only allowed two dogs where I live.  So I need to say for the assignment that what I'm doing is physically acquiring a pet, not just adding a name to an array.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your explanation. getDog() suggests, to me at least, that the function will return a 'dog' (like with a getter function / method), rather than a real world action of getting/obtaining a dog. Perhaps adoptDog() then, as that seems to be what you are doing. Anyway, it's subjective, and it's up to you, just thought I'd mention it in case it was helpful. Best wishes.